# Closing an App Script sidebar containing a form

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, server, client

I have a Google Apps Script running a html-form in the sidebar.
The form-answers are used to generate documents. My problem is that I want to close the sidebar when the program has completed (after clicking Submit).

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="name" type="text"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.withFailureHandler(fail).
                                        withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).
                                        doStuff(this.parentNode)"/>

</form>
```

The program runs as intended if I remove the withSuccessHandler, otherwise it doesn't. Are there a way for me to close the sidebar at the end of doStuff()?

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars): The sidebar can close itself either by calling google.script.host.close() in the client side of an HTML-service interface or UiInstance.close() in a UI-service interface. The sidebar cannot be closed by other interfaces, only by the user or itself.

UiInstance is marked Deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onclick()` attribute can have multiple functions in it.  You can put the `google.script.host.close()` statement after all the code.  Just make sure to put a semi-colon at the end of all the `google.script.run` stuff:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" 
  onclick="google.script.run.withFailureHandler(fail)
  .doStuff(this.parentNode); google.script.host.close();"/>
```

Your packing a lot of code into the `onclick()` attribute.  You could have a separate function:

```
onclick="serverCall();"

window.serverCall = function() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(fail)
    .doStuff(this.parentNode);

  google.script.host.close();
};
```