# Sidebar not closing after function run on 'submit' - Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code run when the submit button is clicked in my HTML service (Google Apps Script):

window.onload = function() {

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
    .addEventListener('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 

            for(var i = 0; i<=33; i++) {

textInputArray.push(sortable.children[i].innerHTML);

$("#meeting" + i).val(textInputArray[i]);

}         
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {google.script.host.close()}).handleFormSubmit(this);                   
    }
    )};
```

It works great, except that the sidebar does not close once the function has been run. I thought this would happen because of the google.script.host.close() but I guess I have this int he wrong place... can anyone see how this needs to be amended?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing an App Script sidebar containing a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179339/closing-an-app-script-sidebar-containing-a-form)

Comment: Related: [Close sidebar then process form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49268356/1595451)

Comment: In your case, if an error occurs at ``handleFormSubmit()``, ``withSuccessHandler()`` is not run. So ``host.close()`` is not run. Can you confirm ``handleFormSubmit()`` again? In my environment, I could confirm that when no error occurs at ``handleFormSubmit()``, ``withSuccessHandler()`` was run and also ``host.close()`` was run.

Comment: For example, when you use this ``google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function() {google.script.host.close()}).handleFormSubmit(this);``, if ``host.close()`` is run, you can confirm that an error occurs at ``handleFormSubmit()``.